# Calculating volume using multiple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

So I have this restriction $$B=\{(x,y,z)\,\,|\,\, (4x+4y+2z)^2+(4x+2y+4z)^2+(2x+4y+4z)^2\leq1\}$$ so I am trying to do integration by substitution: $$u=4x+4y+2z$$   $$v=4x+2y+4z$$  $$w=2x+4y+4z$$
$$\left|\det\left(\frac{\partial(u,v,w)}{\partial(x,y,z)}\right)\right|=40$$ so $$u^2+v^2+w^2\leq1$$
but now I am not sure how to proceed with $$\int\int\int_Bdxdydz = \int\int\int_{newB}(something)dudvdw$$ because I have to use this 40 somehow, but I am not entirely sure how. Please help!
*edit: the answer is : $$\int\int\int_Bdxdydz=\int\int\int_{newB}\frac 1 {40} dudvdw = \frac \pi {30}$$

Comment: $40$ is the determinant of the Jacobian so it appears in the argument of the new integral

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant which may help here

Comment: @SineoftheTime yeah but isn't there supposed to be something additional? Just putting in 40 looks wrong

Comment: @SpaceNugget Something additional like what? Maybe you are referring to the argument of the integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B=\{(x,y,z)\,\,|\,\, (4x+4y+2z)^2+(4x+2y+4z)^2+(2x+4y+4z)^2\leq1\}$$
If you consider the change of variable:

$$u=4x+4y+2z$$

$$v=4x+2y+4z$$

$$w=2x+4y+4z$$
You find that:
\begin{cases}
x=\dfrac{6}{5}u-\dfrac{4}{5}v-\dfrac{3}{10}w\\
y=-\dfrac{4}{5}u+\dfrac{7}{10}v+\dfrac{1}{5}w \\
z=-\dfrac{3}{10}u+\dfrac{1}{5}v+\dfrac{1}{5}w
\end{cases}
When you compute the Jacobian associated to this diffeomorphism you obtain:
$$\det (J_{\varphi})=\dfrac{1}{40} $$
Now, the new domain is:
$$B'=\{(u,v,w)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \,|\, u^2+v^2+w^2\leq1\}$$
It follows that
$$\iiint_B\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z=\iiint_{B'}\frac 1 {40} \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}w = \frac{1}{40} \text{Vol}(B')=\frac{\pi}{30}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the linear map $T$ given by
$$
T(x,y,z):=4\left(x+y+\frac1{2}z,x+\frac1{2}y+z,\frac1{2}x,y,z\right)=(u,v,w)
$$
Therefore $T$ can be represented by the matrix
$$
[T]:=4\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&\frac1{2}\\1&\frac1{2}&1\\\frac1{2}&1&1
\end{bmatrix}\implies \det [T]=4^3\cdot \left(\frac{3}{2}-2-\frac1{8}\right)
=-4^3\cdot \frac{5}{8}=-40
$$
so $T$ is invertible, and we have that

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{A}d(u,v,w)&=\int_{A}d(T(x,y,z))\\&=\int_{T^{-1}(A)}|\det \partial T(x,y,z)|d(x,y,z)\\&=\int_{T^{-1}(A)}|\det [T]|d(x,y,z)\\
&=40 \int_{B}d(x,y,z)
\end{align*}
$$
as when $T$ is linear we have that $\partial T\mathbf{v}=T$ for every vector $\mathbf{v}$, and in this case we have that $T^{-1}(A)=B$ for $A:=\mathbb{B}((0,0,0),1)$.∎